# Symfony - Create route in external JS File

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I have an external .js file where I put all my ajax functions, e.g.

```
        $.getJSON(HVZ_priceCityAjax, {
            rating: rating.val(),
            comment: comment.val(),
            name: name.val(),
            returnTo: returnTo.val()
        })
        .done(function (data) {

        });
```

I would like the URL to be created by a Symfony route, directly inside the .js file, like that:

```
        $.getJSON('{{ path('ajaxPriceCity') }}', {
        ...
```

Is that possible at all?
[FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) does not work with **Symfony3**.

My current way:

*On all pages (to define them and avoid 'undefined' errors):*

```
<script>
   HVZ_priceCityAjax = false;
   HVZ_priceZipAjax = false;
   moreRules = false;
   ...
</script>
```

*On the page that needs the function:*

```
<script>
   HVZ_priceCityAjax = '{{ path('ajaxPriceCity') }}';
</script>
```

This is the only solution I came up with, but that does not seem very efficient.

Is there another way, w/out FOSJsRoutingBundle?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make your js file a template.

**someJavascript.js.twig**

```
$.getJSON('{{ path('ajaxPriceCity') }}', {
    ...
```

Then, include it:

```
<script>
    {{ include('someJavascript.js.twig') }}
</script>
```

Note: there are other ways to get the template into the place you want, but this is for purposes of explination.

Comment: Where do I have to put the .js.twig file? currently it is in my web/assets/... with the other js files. But that gives me `Unable to find template "assets/vendor/hvz-main/js/frontend.js.twig"`

Comment: I would put it where the rest of your templates are. to keep things tidy